# case when for empty parameter

Tags: sql, select, parameters, case

```
declare @customer varchar(50)

select cateogry, product_Name 
from product 
join order 
on product.id = order.product_id
join customer 
on order.customer_id = cutstomer.id 
where category = 'Tea'
and customer_name =
case 
when @customer is not null 
then @customer 
else 
'%'
end
```

above query did not work correctly, 
as parameter could be empty sometimes.

Comment: That is non-standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The `=` operator doesn't support wildcards. You should use the `like` operator instead:

```
SELECT category, product_Name 
FROM   product 
JOIN   order ON product.id = order.product_id
JOIN   customer ON order.customer_id = cutstomer.id 
WHERE  category = 'Tea' AND
       customer_name LIKE -- Here!
       CASE WHEN @customer IS NOT NULL THEN @customer 
       ELSE '%'
       END
```

Alternatively, you could just short-circuit it with the `or` operator:

```
SELECT category, product_Name 
FROM   product 
JOIN   order ON product.id = order.product_id
JOIN   customer ON order.customer_id = cutstomer.id 
WHERE  category = 'Tea' AND
       (@customer IS NULL OR customer_name = @customer)
```

Comment: it certainly helps.  some rows return is better than empty data set.

Answer (score 0):

use like when the parameter is not sure to have value or not

```
declare @customer varchar(50)

select cateogry, product_Name 
from product 
join order 
on product.id = order.product_id
join customer 
on order.customer_id = cutstomer.id 
where category = 'Tea'
and customer_name like
case 
when @customer is not null 
then @customer 
else 
'%'
end
```